# Mysql Query to fetch users who and all following the intrest?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a app where a users can follow 'n' number of intrests.here I need to fetch the users who and all following a each intrest.for your information i have three tables as bellow

1)tbl_intrestmaster(master table for intrests)

2)tbl_users(master table)

3)tbl_userintrests(fk to tbl_intrestmaster and tbl_user)

I can do it but without processing in programming language i want to achieve this ie by using mysql query only.

Comment: `I need to fetch the users who and all following a each intrest`. What?

Comment: do you want to get username and intrestname  from tbl_userintrests for each interest? please clear your question

Comment: yes i need all users who following the each intrest

Answer (score 0):

So, tbl_userintrests (interest?) is a join table between users and interests? And, you're trying to get users who follow each interest? Ok, something like this:

```
SELECT u.name, i.name
FROM tbl_userintrests ui
JOIN tbl_users u
ON u.id = ui.user_id
JOIN tbl_intrestmaster i
ON i.id = ui.interst_id
```

So you're basically saying:

Give me everything in the join table
Match users onto it
Match interests onto it
Now you should be left with users matching interests

For the record, this is a very simple join table question and you may find some value in searching SO / Google for other join table examples.

Comment: Yes it is.it will give repetation in array like {user1,intrestname1},{user1,intrestname2},{user2,intrestname1}

Comment: Is that not what you want?

Comment: I need the result as following array

Comment: Array
(
    [intrest1] => Array
        (
            [0] => user1
            [1] => user2
            .
            .
        )

    [intrest2] => Array
        (
            [0] => user1
            [1] => user3
            .
            .
        )
)